# How to resolve "Cannot find module" in Typescript Github Action test?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, npm, visual-studio-code, github-actions

When I create a new repo from the [Github Actions Typescript template](https://github.com/actions/typescript-action), and check it out locally, I keep having the same problem:
I open the source in VS code, and can work on it all fine, installing, building and running the tests according to the template's readme also works as intended.

But when I try to write tests for my action I keep getting `Cannot find module [someModule] or its corresponding type declarations.` and `Cannot find name [someName].`errors.
Here's what it looks like when freshly created from template (a lot of red):
[image]

Note that 'npm test'  runs fine with this, so the issue should be with VS Code...I suppose?
I've tried the suggestions offered by VS code, and did a lot of googleing, but sadly every bit of info is about how to run your tests using Github Actions, not about how to fix issues with testing your action.

I am not very experienced in the typescript and npm ecosystem, so this might be a beginner's question, but I'd be very grateful if someone could point me to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

`npm i -D @types/node @types/jest`

Then in your `tsconfig.json` add:

`"types": ["node"]`